# java.lang.SecurityException for a content:// URI

Tags: android

I have a program flow where I ask user to choose an App for clicking a picture and then on receiving the captured image URI, I then facilitate choosing an App for Cropping it -- both the capture and crop Activities not being mine.

The problem occurs when I receive the captured URI and try sending it to other App for cropping. You see, since the App that captured it and created the URI is different from the one that will crop it, I am getting `java.lang.SecurityException` from the Crop App, something like this:

> *Uid 10159 does not have permission to uri 0 @ content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F74090/ORIGINAL/NONE/1104144717*

Here is the code I have written for sending the image:

```
intent.setDataAndType(mImageCaptureUri, "image/*");

intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, (String)null);

this.startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
```

The question is, how can I facilitate this other Cropping App permission to write on this URI?

Comment: you cant grant write permission, only owner of `com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider` can do that

Comment: @pskink : Okay. Then, is there any way I can somehow extract the image content out of the URI and make it "mine" for it to give?

Comment: use `InputStream` to copy `Uri`'s content to some your location - see `ContentResolver` API docs on how to do that